# Using Walled Garden to Secure Guest Wi-Fi from LAN/WLAN

Tags: wifi

I’m trying to secure our LAN/WLAN while still providing quality guest Wi-Fi access. I came across a concept labeled “walled garden” with minimal instruction/explanation, stating that to use this feature I needed to include the desired range of IP addresses using CIDR notation. If I use a range such as 10.50.0.1/16 to 10.50.255.254/16 and then configure the firewall settings to deny all traffic on 10.50.0.0/16 from accessing any other internal IP addresses, will this secure my guest Wi-Fi and prevent guest devices from being able to access our equipment on our LAN/WLAN? If it would work with some minor tweaks, what changes need to be made?

Comment: You may just want to get an outside company to provide guest access. Many businesses are doing this because of the legal problems of guest users doing something illegal from your network. It is also possible that a guest can get your public address banned from other networks.

Comment: For example, the spammer using your guest network to spam SE sites can get your address banned by SE, and then you cannot use [sf]. That may be inconvenient, but the nut who researches and buys materials for explosives can get your network taken over by the ATF, FBI, and local law enforcement while it is searched for evidence, or if he actually hurts someone, the lawsuits because your company doesn't have the same legal protections as ISPs.

Comment: Good insights, thank you. In the event that we may not be in a position to afford hiring an outside company, what then can we do?

Comment: Regarding your comment on my other posting: Thank you Ron - I did not realize that cross-posting was not permitted, so I will delete the post on the other sites and work on including the information requested.